# How can I share code between test module and app module? - Fakes depend on code from app module

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, testing, android-testing

I want to be able to create a separate test-shared module to be able to share between the androidTest and test packages. My issue is the fakes require code from the app module (Repository, Data Models, DTO's, etc.) and cannot see that code if put it in the separate test-shared module.

Do I need to create fakes for *everything* to be able to share the code between the test packages? Seems excessive.

Or is there actually a way to have the test-shared module import dependencies from the app module? That would be convenient.

I am new at this so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Resource: https://blog.danlew.net/2022/08/16/sharing-code-between-test-modules/

Here is an example of one of my fakes that requires code from the app module. - (Crypto Repository, CoinDto, CoinDetailsDto)

```
class FakeRepository : CryptoRepository {

    override suspend fun getCoinData(): List<CoinDto> {

        val data = CoinDto(
            id = "id",
            is_active = true,
            is_new = true,
            name = "Test Coin",
            rank = 1,
            symbol = "Test Symbol",
            type = "Test Type"
        )

        return listOf(data)
    }

    override suspend fun getCoinDetails(id: String): CoinDetailsDto {

        return CoinDetailsDto(
            description = "Test Description",
            developmentStatus = "Test Status",
            firstDataAt = "Test Data At",
            hardwareWallet = true,
            hashAlgorithm = "Test Hash Algorithm",
            id = "id",
            isActive = true,
            isNew = true,
            lastDataAt = "Test Last Data At",
            links = fakeLink,
            linksExtended = fakeLinksExtended,
            logo = "https://static.coinpaprika.com/coin/bnb-binance-coin/logo.png",
            message = "Test Message",
            name = "Test Coin Name",
            openSource = true,
            orgStructure = "Test Org Structure",
            proofType = "Test Proof Type",
            rank = 1,
            startedAt = "Test Started At",
            symbol = "TTC",
            tags = listOf(fakeTag),
            team = listOf(fakeTeamMember),
            type = "Test Type"
        )
    }

    override suspend fun getPriceCoinDetails(id: String): CoinPriceDetailsDtoItem {

        return CoinPriceDetailsDtoItem(
            beta_value = 0.5,
            circulating_supply = 1000L,
            first_data_at = "Test First Data At",
            id = "id",
            last_updated = "Test Last Data At",
            max_supply = 10000L,
            name = "Tes Coin Name",
            quotes = fakeQuotes,
            rank = 1,
            symbol = "TTC",
            total_supply = 1000L
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: One way would be to extract reusable things from the app module into their own module (business stuff). This way your shared module can depend on it without depending on the app.

Comment: Just use [Java Test Fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures).

Answer (score 1):

I just did this couple weeks ago.
After create your shared test module. You have to provide every implementation that your shared test is needed. Then also

`implementation(project(":app"))`

If your project have mutiple product flavors then you have to define all off them in you shared module like this:

```
android {
    flavorDimensions.add("env")
    productFlavors {
        create("dev") {
            dimension = "env"
        }

        create("staging") {
            dimension = "env"
        }

        create("production") {
            dimension = "env"
        }
}
```

And add this in app build.gradle

```
    testImplementation(project(":SharedTest"))
    androidTestImplementation(project(":SharedTest"))
```

Hope it is work for you!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this today and let you know how it goes.